# How to deploy SQL Scripts on BigQuery Dataset?

Tags: deployment, google-bigquery

I have few create table and procedure sql scripts that I want to deploy on my BigQuery dataset. I am looking for a Oracle's "@" or Snowflake's  "!Source" equivalent in BigQuery.

I am new to BigQuery and have I not tried to create a object using sql file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple table & routine creation in `BigQuery`:

```
-- Create table mytable
CREATE TABLE `mydataset.mytable`
(
  id INTEGER,
  name STRING
);

-- Insert values into mytable
INSERT INTO `mydataset.mytable` VALUES (1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2');

-- Select values from mytable
SELECT * FROM `mydataset.mytable`;

-- Creating a stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE `mydataset.myproc`()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM `mydataset.mytable` LIMIT 10;
END;

-- Executing a stored procedure
CALL `mydataset.myproc`();

-- Dropping a table
DROP TABLE `mydataset.mytable`;

-- Dropping a procedure
DROP PROCEDURE `mydataset.mytable`;
```

Reference: [BigQuery DDL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language) & [Procedural languages](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language)

If you want execute scripts from a SQL script file - one option is to use `bq command-line tool` for example:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < sqlbackup.sql
```

Reference: [bq command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ratish Kumar. How do I provide the file location? Is there a requirement for the file to be on google drive?

Comment: The file can be placed on Google cloud storage or export from the local machine (laptop). You have to install gcloud SDK on your machine, refer gcloud SDK installation guide - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install. If you upload files to GCS bucket, easy option is to use Cloud Shell (gcloud SDKs are preinstalled) - refer https://cloud.google.com/shell. If this answer satisfies your requirement, accept the answer. Thanks!